# Can someone help me understand how this Pig Latin iteration works in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iteration

```
def pig_latin_word(word)
  vowels = "aeiou"

  if vowels.include?(word[0])
     return word + "yay"
  end

  word.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
    if vowels.include?(char)
      return word[i..-1] + word[0...i] + "ay"
    end
  end
end
```

Regarding the method, assuming the code takes in the input "banana", it returns "ananabay". But if I'm iterating through each character in the string, wouldn't the last iterated vowel be the one the new Pig Latin word is created from?

In other words, what is the reason behind "banana" returning "ananabay" as opposed to returning "abananay"?

Comment: I've tried to give a step-by-step explanation of how the code evaluates, but I don't understand why you thought `word[i..-1] + word[0...i]` would result in `"abanan"`. I guess you somehow thought that `word[1..-1]` means "only the second letter"?! And you thought that `word[0...1]` means "the whole word, excluding the last letter"?! It's really hard for me to see how you reached this conclusion, so perhaps elaborating your train of thought here would be useful for someone to explain which parts of the language you've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, what is the reason behind "banana" returning "ananabay" as opposed to returning "abananay"?

Let's step through the code one line at a time:

```
if vowels.include?(word[0])
```

Is the first letter of `"banana"` a vowel? No, so this first block doesn't evaluate.

```
word.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
```

This is iterating through each letter of the word

On the **first iteration**, `char = "b"` and `i = 0`.

```
if vowels.include?(char)
```

Is `"b"` a vowel? No, so the block doesn't evaluate.

Next iteration... Now, `char = "a"` and `i = 1`.

Is `"a"` a vowel? **Yes**, so the block evaluates. Let's see what it says:

```
return word[i..-1] + word[0...i] + "ay"
```

- `word[1..-1]` means "everything from the **second letter** of `word`, up to *and including* the **last letter**, i.e. `"anana"`.
- `word[0...1]` means "everything from the **first letter** of `word`, up to *but excluding* the **second letter**. In other words, only the first letter: `"b"`.
- Concatenate them together, and you get: `"anana" + "b" + "ay"`, i.e. `"ananabay"`.

Comment: This result shouldn't be surprising, because [that's how piglatin is supposed to work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin).

Comment: Thank you for the step-by-step explanation!

My confusion came from why after the second iteration, why don't we continue to iterate? Doesn't the .each mean we should be iterating through the entire string, in turn giving us a new return value?

Comment: **OH!**.... OK, I wish you'd elaborated earlier, because that's a very short and simple question to answer: The `return` keyword means "return from this method, immediately, with this value. Everything after the first `return` keyword is never reached. You can't `return` more than once. This is the same in every programming language, not just ruby.

Comment: So in this example, the third iteration is never reached - because we `return`ed on the second iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much, this clarified things for me!